# bash alias cp='cp -i' not work as expectation in script

Tags: bash, alias

```
#!/bin/bash

alias cp='cp -i'
alias           # this line output: "alias cp='cp -i'"
touch /tmp/{a,b}.txt
cp /tmp/a.txt /tmp/b.txt  # this line doesn't work as my expectation
```

I expect it will show prompt at end, like this: "cp: overwrite ‘/tmp/b.txt’?"

Comment: I add `shopt` in script it shows `expand_aliases  off`, and in the `man bash`: `expand_aliases: If set, aliases are expanded as described above under ALIASES.  This option is enabled by default for interactive shells.`

Comment: Why do you configure your shell for alias expansion to be turned off, when you want alias expansion to happen? BTW, most people consider it a bad idea to use aliases in a script, and I think this is the reason why it is turned off by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because bash script is run in non-interactive mode. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

or

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
> expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt.

See asnwers to: [How to run an alias in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script)

Alternatively, you can use shell functions instead of aliases. Check answer to: [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)